# Php artisan migrate - unexpected 'string' (T_STRING)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

When I run `php artisan migrate` to make the tables for my databases in Laravel I get the following error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

I think that this error is quite useless since it doesn't tell me in what file, and what place something is wrong (and that makes it very hard to understand what's going on).

The migration seems to fail with the first migration since it didn't generate a single table in my database.

This is the migration (User -> generated with php artisan make:auth):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('avatar');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

It is just the default migration with one new line. I can't find out what's wrong with it. I already tried `composer dump-autoload` and `composer clearcache` but nothing works.

I hope somebody knows a solution.

EDIT: it appears to happen before the first migration runs. Is there a file where something might be wrong?

You can read my Laravel.log file here: https://pastebin.com/1PrDwady

Comment: What is this? $table->avatar('password');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks from your [stack trace](https://pastebin.com/1PrDwady) as though you may have accidentally edited the function definition for `string()` at this point:
`C:\xampp\htdocs\urenlijstje\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint.php:473`

One of the variable names is likely missing the `$` indicating to the PHP parser that it is indeed a variable.

Here is the [line of code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L473) as it should be in Laravel 5.4.

In situations like this where the framework won't boot, I've often traced back issues to inadvertent edits like this. Since your `vendor` directory is not in source control (or shouldn't be at least!), another option is to `rm -rf vendor && composer install` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I have no idea how, or why but the whole 'function' word was missing. It was just: public string(). I couldn't find it with version control (git). But it's fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only error I see here is `avatar`. There is obviously no `avatar` type, so it should be probably:

```
$table->string('avatar');
```

If you still see the error, verify exact line and make sure you are running valid version of PHP (it should be 5.6+).

If it doesn't help, try to leave empty `up` method to verify if error still persist. It might be in different place of application (for example ServiceProvider) and not directly in this migration.

Comment: I know, this was a small mistake but I forgot to edit it in this question. I still get the same error in when I try to migrate. My PHP version is 7.0.9 and it still appears when up() is empty. I will try it on a different pc to check if something is wrong with my PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Is this $table->avatar('password'); supposed to be $table->string('avatar');

Comment: Yes it is, this was a small mistake but I forgot to edit it in this question. I still get the same error in when I try to migrate.

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is wrong in that file. Im wondering if there is something wrong in the routes file? Or another file that is executed before this?

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong in my routes... Very weird. I will try it on another pc. Maybe it is a problem with my PHP. (And I added the logs to the question).